# Serve KML and KMZ from PHP

Tags: php, apache, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

### Edit:

There is no problem with the code. The problem lies within google map which caches maps, and also the upload speed of the webserver which hosted the map.

So this question actually does not need an answer. The codes work well.

---

Due to security reason, I am putting my map files (.kml and .kmz) in a web inaccessible directory.
The idea is that I want to serve the maps only to authorized users.

Let's say i got test.kml.
I copied one to `C:/xampp/htdocs/test.kml` (web accessible).
And another to `D:/authorized/test.kml` (web inaccessible).

I will serve the web inaccessible files from a PHP script, lets call it getmap.php. And with the help of apache mod_rewrite, http://example.com/getmap/test.kml will be served by getmap.php with the value of `$_GET['path']` will be test.kml

**getmap.php**

```
<?php
//Get the file path and extension, check for existence
$filepath = 'D:/authorized/'.$_GET['path'];
if (!file_exists($filepath) || is_dir($filepath)) die('file not found');
$filename = basename($filepath);
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

//Perhaps the cookies header is the problem, perhaps not
header_remove('x-powered-by');
header_remove('Set-Cookie');
header_remove('Expires');
header_remove('Cache-Control');

//Set the content type based on file extension
if ($ext == 'kml') header('Content-Type: application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml');
else if ($ext == 'kmz') header('Content-Type: application/vnd.google-earth.kmz');

//The other headers that possibly required
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filepath));
header('Connection: close');

readfile($filepath);
die();
?>
```

Then i display it with a html with googlemap:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=LordOfTheKey-NotRing"></script>
    <style>
      #themap{width:800px; height:500px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="themap"></div>
    <script>
      var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-15.869167, -47.920834),
        zoom: 3,
        disableDefaultUI: false
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('themap'), mapOptions);

      var mapuri = 'http://example.com/test.kml';
      var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(mapuri,
        {suppressInfoWindow: false,map:map}
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The map was shown no problem when accessed from mapuri='http://example.com/test.kml' which is the direct file link. The file is served directly by apache.

But when mapuri='http://example.com/getmap/test.kml' where the file will be served by the getmap.php script above, the script only works for points and polylines map types. For raster types, the map just won't show.

I've tried checking the web response using telnet example.com 80, made sure it returned http 200, proper Content-Type, even removed Set-Cookies header. But it just won't work for certain map types. Any Ideas?

Comment: To use KmlLayer to display KML, the file must be publicly available (Google's servers will access it directly)

Comment: @geocodezip it seems it is publicly available. It's just that it isn't a static file but instead it's generated with php.  I'd try downloading it in incognito mode, then comparing it to static kml file you have in htdocs

Comment: It certainly isn't clear to me from the question, perhaps the issue is the MIME type it is being served with.

Comment: By your comments, i tried to reproduce the problem at cloud9. https://ide.c9.io/fandisus/showmap. But turns out there is no problem with the code in cloud9. All is well at cloud9. Now i really dont know where to look. @amenadiel i tried, and checked the content with notepad++. The files are exactly the same.

Comment: Tried the code on another unix server with the same framework. Guess the problem lies somewhere in the webserver setting: httpd.conf or php.ini. Or in the operating system (Windows Server).